# If $\int |x|^2 f(x) dx<\infty$ then $f(x) \le c |x|^{-d-2}$?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, inequality, improper-integrals, spherical-coordinates

Let $f$ be a non-negative function on $\mathbb R^d$ satisfying the following:

(1) There exists a non-increasing function $g$ on $(0,\infty)$ such that

(1-i) $ C_1^{-1} g(|x|) \le f(x) \le C_1 g(|x|) $ for some constant $C_1\ge 1$,

(1-ii) $g(|x|) \le C_2 g(|x|+1), \ |x|\ge 1 $ for some constant  $C_2 \ge 1$,

(2) $\int |x|^2 f(x) \ dx < \infty $

I want to claim that $f(x) \le c |x|^{-d-2}$ by the integrability condition, using change of variables (polar coordinate), but can't prove it. I wonder if it does not hold for some $f$.

Comment: I’m trying to prove your claim, but I encountered problems with integrability. Are you considering Riemann or Lebesgue integrals? Is the function $g$ continuous?

Comment: Under some assumptions we can proceed as follows. Conditions (1) and (3) imply that $I=\int |x|^2 g(|x|)<\infty$. Switching $I$ to polar coordinates, we obtain that $I=C_3\int_0^\infty g(t)t^{d+1}dt$ for some constant $C_3>0$. ... . which yields the required bound for $f(x)$.

Comment: How does this yields the requested bound ?